# General AdMob not testing questions

Tags: iphone, ios, admob

I have a couple of questions regarding AdMob before releasing my app.

1 . When AdMob fails to load ad, what happens?

If AdMob doesn't load ads for some reason, internet connection or any other reasons, what happens then? Does it become hidden automatically? Or will it be displayed with a blank banner?

2 . Do I need this code when I'm not testing the app?

Currently I use this code to settup and display the AdMob for testing on simulator:

```
//Adding adMob
adMobBannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 430, 320, 50)];
adMobBannerView_.adUnitID = @"xxx";
adMobBannerView_.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:adMobBannerView_];

GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"GAD_SIMULATOR_ID", nil];
[adMobBannerView_ loadRequest:request];
```

But do I need the `request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"GAD_SIMULATOR_ID", nil];` when I am not testing anymore? Should I remove it? Should I replace it with some other code?

I hope you understand my questions, please tell me if this wasn't understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If no ad has previously been served then you will get a blank banner. Otherwise it will redisplay the last ad you received.
2. You don't need the code, but it won't hurt to keep it there.